# Java arrays value setting

Tags: java, arrays

How do I add an array value to another array while increasing the array value of the other array each time.  For example, if I want array1 value to be added to array2 and when I search for the array2[position] it appears as the value of array1.

```
array1[position]=array2[count]
```

I kind of want it so that it is looped but I don't know how

Comment: Arrays can't resize. Use `ArrayList`.

Comment: You can't resize `arrays`. Use `List` type.

Comment: I can't see where OP is asking to resize arrays. I think this question needs to be reworded for clarity.

Comment: Your question is unclear, at least to me. Could you share some more code, showing the array you have and the result you're trying to get, please?

Comment: I have an array that contains a list of items and the user should choose an item to add to their cart (which is another array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment -> Its going to get clumsy if you insist on arrays - using ArrayList will be much easier:

```
ArrayList<Item> cart = new ArrayList<>();

cart.add(array1[position]);
```

If you insist on using arrays you must create a new array with larger size and copy the old array into the new array each time you run out of space - actually this is what ArrayList does for your (albeit in a clever way - increasing size by 50% each time it runs out of space)

Comment: I have an array (array1) which contains a list of items and the user should choose an item to add to their cart (array2).  So if the user chooses item array1[position] it should equal to array2[0] and their next item should equal array2[1] and so one

Comment: Which is exactly what the above code will do - if you use ArrayList. Is it necessary to use arrays? - PS: You can retrieve an item from a specific place in an Arraylist with cart.get(index)